# Table View numberOfSections method is not getting called in swift3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have swift 3 conversion code working fine.For change of app features I have implemented

> numberOfSections

but it's never called. I did not understand why? My Controller is UIViewController and TableView added from storyboard. TableView datasource is connected to current view controller. I am getting other data source method called like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

but never called

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 3
}
```

Comment: Did you add the `override` keyword, as in: `override func numberOfSections...` ?

Comment: MyClass is subclass of UIViewController where  I set datasource of table view to my class so I don't need to write override @MichaelDautermann

Comment: As @MichaelDautermann mentioned... check that you have "override" . I miss Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you set up the tableView's dataSource but just to make sure try setting up again in your code again like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  tableView.delegate = self
  tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: your answer seems to be right but i don't know what is reason. I am checking what might be reason or apple changed anything on it!

Comment: looks like you didn't set properly the connection of delegate and dataSource  of your tableView and ViewController in the storyboard otherwise you shouldn't need to implement the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing it like:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

Do it like this:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

Comment: swift 3 don't want last case (

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem. Appending UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource to my class fixed the problem immediately, the compiler telling exactly what I'd been missing, etc.

Seems like UICollectionView in Swift is pre-checking for conformity on a protocol-basis rather than on a method-basis. My implementation of "numberOfSections" was perfectly fine, for instance, but simply wasn't called without the conformity declaration.